# Export nested variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, export

Please bear with me as I try to explain. I would like to export a value once the if statement is satisfied from a nested variable, then import this into another .ts file.

Example.

```
var create = {

if(condition == true){

 var x = 3;

export x;

    }

else return;

}
```

then when its done

```
import { x } from "./List"

if(x == 3){

make condition here true.

}
```

Comment: try make it export default x

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to note here:

1. exports need to be top level, you can't export something from inside a function or a branch.
2. you can modify an exported variable, but only from inside the module
3. from 1. it follows that a module cannot have a variable number of exports based on a condition. You always export the same number of elements, but some of them may be undefined.

Taking this into account, what you probable need is to set a variable that will be set to different values depending on your conditions and then **always** export it. Something like this:

```
let x = null; //maybe undefined, or another default value

if(condition == true){
 x = 3;
}

export x;
```